# Is this usage of から correct?

Tags: grammar, particle-から

私は私のまちにやすめから、「name of town」がすきです.

I like my hometown because I can relax here.

Comment: から (meaning because) comes after the dictionary form of the verb (やすむ in this case). Not withstanding that, I think your sentence sounds rather awkward, but I'm not sufficiently confident to correct it.

Comment: So can you not use から with the え form to say can?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wasn't thinking properly. You can, but it would still be dictionary form やすめる.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> くつろげるから「name of town」がすきです.

or

> くつろぐことができるから「name of town」がすきです.

sounds right to my ears.

休むことができるから seems more like "because I can take a rest" or "because I don't have to go to work here."

As for the usage of "から" itself, your sentence was correct.

Answer (score 1):

休むことができるから would compensate the translation better i think.